# How to use angular-gauge with ionic 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I'm trying to use Angular-gauge: https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-gauge/tree/ba9783f1531251bd8727899cf440c5889ff2b32e

With my ionic 2 project.

But that don't work.

I have add in the app.module the import.

```
imports: [

    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp), 
    GaugeModule
```

Then I add in a page in the html:

```
<mwl-gauge [max]="100" [dialStartAngle]="-90" [dialEndAngle]="-90.001" [value]="50" [animated]="true" [animationDuration]="1"></mwl-gauge>
```

And then I obtain the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined at updateGauge
```

[image]

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: are you using that specific tree or the master?

Comment: version 1.0.0. npm install --save angular-gauge@1.0.0